# How to use Play 2 "doc" command?

Tags: scala, playframework, scaladoc

Play seem to generate documentation thru "build" or "doc" commands.

How are we supposed to use this feature ?

- Is it generating text files ?
- Is it generating html files ?
- How can i consult this doc ?
- Is it even made for humans or is it an internal thing ?

Comment: Run it and find out.

Comment: Indeed i realized the path was provided by the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doc` command isn't specific to Play. Since play/activator wrap sbt, they inherit the `sbt doc` command, which will generate scaladocs for all the source files in a project. Running it is pretty self explanatory. you'll see output like this:

```
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /path/to/project/target/scala-2.10/api...
```

And if you navigate to that directory, you'll see a bunch of generated html files containing the scaladocs for your project. So yes, it's generating html files, and yes it's meant for humans. Opening `target/scala-2.10/api/index.html` will be much more telling.